# I have a simple pedigree database and would like to structure a query that will return name rather than id

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a pedigree database pretty simple columns are pedigreeid (auto-increment primary key), name (name of the animal), damid, sireid. Every animal has a pedigreeid, this same pedigreeid is used as damid or sireid once the animal has offspring. I want to return the most popular sire - the sire with the most kids in the database by name but I'm having trouble doing that.

My sql query is lame and needs work.

This query works to return the 50 most popular sires by id:

```
SELECT pedigreeid, name, sireid, count(sireid) AS popular
FROM pedigree
GROUP BY sireid
ORDER BY popular 
DESC LIMIT 50
```

but for name and pedigreeid it simply returns the first offspring who has that most popular sire as sire. It doesn't return the sire's name (I can go and look it up using the umbers in the sireid column but want to write a query that does it.

Comment: Where is the PHP code? Is it relevant at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a self subquery to get this kind of information; your current selection of pedigreeid and name are almost nonsense (they are the pedigreeid and name of one offspring of the sireid).

This query will get you the id and number of offspring of the most popular sires:

```
SELECT sireid, COUNT(*) AS numOffspring 
FROM pedigree 
GROUP BY sireid 
ORDER BY numOffspring DESC
LIMIT 50
```

*ORDER BY is needed above to get the 50 most popular.*

Now, you need to get the sires' data:

```
SELECT s.pedigreeid, s.name, popular.numOffSpring
FROM (
   -- The above query goes here
) AS popular 
INNER JOIN pedigree AS s ON popular.sireid = s.pedigreeid
ORDER BY popular.numOffspring DESC
```

*The ORDER BY needs repeated in the outer query because you cannot rely on order from a subquery to be preserved through a JOIN.*

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. You're right, my query was nonsense.

Comment: @HerronHill in case it was taken as such, I didn't intend "nonsense" in an insulting or derogatory way, just as a description for the data you'd end up receiving.

Comment: Very nice of you but you were right the first time, it was nonsense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To pull out the name of the sireid, you could add a self-join to your aggregate query, like :

```
SELECT 
    t2.pedigreeid, 
    t2.name
    count(*) popular
FROM
     pedigree t1
    INNER JOIN pedigree t2 ON t1.sireid = t2.pedigreeid
GROUP BY
    t2.pedigreeid, 
    t2.name
ORDER BY popular DESC 
LIMIT 50
```